# Django: customizing the Form does not deliver the instructions, input only numbers etc

Tags: django, django-forms

I am in the forms.py file, and as you can see I am trying to customize the html that the template engine renders, but it is ignoring whatever I write. If I enter letters, it should show a dialog box on the fly as HTML5 by default does, indicating that only numbers. Also even if I write a number larger than 10, which is the limit, it sends it anyway. In other words, the customization on the forms.py page is not being effective like when you do it directly on the form. but I cannot write in the form because of the **** template that abstracts everything and you dont know what is going on behind doors. I include the form just for curiosity:

```
class ReForm(forms.Form):

    count = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'input type': 'number', 'pattern':'\d*', 'maxlength':'2', 'min': '1',
            'max':'10','title':'Numbers only','placeholder':'Max value 10'}))
```

FORM:

```
<form method="GET" novalidate>
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden_field }}
  {% endfor %}

  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ field.label_tag }}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your field like this

```
count = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'type': 'number', 'maxlength':2,'size':5,'placeholder':'Number Only'}))
```